# Homework help (unique constraint)

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints, unique

I have some trouble with homework I got that I need to understand.

I have 4 tables:

1: `customer`
2: `order`
3: `orderedproduct`
4. `product`  .

They are linked by foreign keys.

I need to make a unique constraint so that a customer can only place 1 unique order per day. If the same customer wants to order more on the same day, it has to be written on the already existing order.

Tables:

`Customer`:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER 
(
    CUSTOMERNR INT NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR(256), 
    CITY VARCHAR(256),
    PRIMARY KEY (CUSTOMERNR)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

`Order`:

```
CREATE TABLE ORDER 
(
    ORDERNR INT NOT NULL,
    ORDERDATE DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (ORDERNR)),
    FOREIGN KEY (CUSTOMERNR) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CUSTOMERNR)
            ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

`OrderedProduct`:

```
CREATE TABLE ORDEREDPRODUCT 
(
    OPNR INT NOT NULL,
    AMOUNT INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (ORDERNR) REFERENCES ORDER(ORDERNR),
    FOREIGN KEY (PRODUCTCODE) REFERENCES PRODUCT (PRODUCTCODE)
            ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CHECK (AMOUNT => 0)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

`Product`:

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT 
(
    PRODUCTCODE INT NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR(256),
    TYPE VARCHAR(256),
    PRICE FLOAT,
    STOCK INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (PRODUCTCODE),
    CHECK (AMOUNT => 0)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: you shuld show what hav you trie so far.

Comment: I wish I had some [costumers](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%3Acostumer) in my life.  Be able to have some wicked fancy dress parties!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alter table order add unique index(orderdate, COSTUMERNR);
```

Comment: This makes sure that every unique order date has a unique costumer? What about the type i chose (date time) doesn't it work on different times then instead of a whole day?

Comment: yes it will if you are storing a time, you could just be storing a date in ORDERDATE with a time of 00:00:00? I would store date an time time in another field for this purpose called ORDERDATETIME

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to split the datetime column into a date column and a time column, you can use a simple constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE ORDER (
   ORDERNR INT NOT NULL,
   ORDERDATE DATE,
   ORDERTIME TIME,
    ...
CONSTRAINT [UniqueOrder] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
(
   COSTUMERNR, ORDERDATE
)
```